# Store aligned data non aligned

Tags: c++, alignment

Suppose I have a have a class `T` and an array:

```
uint8_t array[sizeof(T)];
```

One thing to note is that `array` might have an alignment which might not be compatible with `T`.

Now the question is: Is there any way to store a `T` in array (despite the alignment issues), provided that we do not try to do any thing with the `T`, until we copy it from the array into a properly aligned storage space?

In other words `array` is just going to be a storage location, until we need to access `T`, at which case we copy it to proper alignment, and use the value, and copy it back into storage.

Note:

`T` may be trivially copyable but it is not guaranteed that `T` is going to be trivially copyable......it could be any class you could think of

So.....is this in any way possible (hopefully standard conforming?)

Comment: `memcpy`, if `T` is trivial?

Comment: What you need is serialization. There are a lot of answers aboit it over there.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*The question is evolving and I'm not going to track it by revising this answer correspondingly.*</sup>

Yes,  for a *trivially copyable* object you can use `memcpy`, and that's used in a (non-normative) example in the standard.

*C++11 §3.9/2:*

> **”** For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`. If the content of the array of `char` or `unsigned char` is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

For template code you can check whether a type is trivially copyable via [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to be trivially copyable (I will edit my question to make that a little clearer)

Comment: @DarthRubik: Instead of revising the question so that it invalidates an existing answer, please ask a new question.

Comment: placement `new` and a move constructor perhaps?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Unfortunately that is undefined behaviour to use if the alignment is not correct